# Makes notes on a mac which contains source code

Tags: notes.app

I love the notes app on the mac. One problem I face is that if I am making notes on the app and try to put some source code in it. the notes app completely screws up the formatting. It will mess up quotations, put line indentations.

It seems that the notes app wants to treat everything as an english sentence.

Is there some way by which I can tell the notes app that I am copying source code into notes so it should not mess it up?

Comment: You may need to add more details because when I paste source code into Notes, under OS X 10.11.5 from e.g. Script Editor, it maintains text formatting, e.g. bold, italic, etc., and tab stops. From TextWrangler it just maintains the tab stops and the text is plain. In either case it's not exhibiting the behavior you've described. What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: Could you add in your OQ which version of MacOS X you are using. On 10.10.5 I don't see this behaviour.